# requestFileSystem ok on Chrome, but undefined on Safari7 and mobile Chrome/Safari

Tags: html, safari, mobile-safari, mobile-chrome

I'm trying to test the HTML5 FileReader API `FileReader.readAsDataURL(file)` on mobile but I'm running into problems. It works fine in desktop Chrome, but fails in Safari and mobile Chrome/Safari

I'm using this line:

   `window.requestFileSystem  = window.requestFileSystem || 
                                  window.webkitRequestFileSystem
   // window.requestFileSystem is undefined on Safari and mobile`

Is there a trick or a setting that I am not using?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This API is deprecated. Look at this article by Eric Bidelman:

http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/file/filesystem/

Also look at compatibility at:

http://caniuse.com/#feat=filesystem

Comment: To the question of: "Can I use filesystem?", the answer is apparently: "No". So that leads to the next question. Something along the lines of: "What do I use instead?" I would think that a possible solution would be webSQL, but that seems like using a database as a substitute for a text file.